# How to filter out false values from the list in racket

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I'm learning Racket (but probably answer will be similar in any Scheme and scheme-derived language) and wonder how to filter out false (#f) values from a given list. The best I came up with is:

```
(filter (lambda (x)
           (not (eq? x #false)))
        '("a" "b" #f 1 #f "c" 3 #f))

'("a" "b" 1 "c" 3) ;; output
```

However, I guess there has to be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just do

```
(filter identity '("a" "b" #f 1 #f "c" 3 #f))
```

as anything not #f is considered true.

Comment: Also, you might see Racket code that uses `values` instead of `identity` (for example when someone is using `#lang racket/base` and doesn't want to `(require racket/function)` just to get `identity`).

Comment: @GregHendershott +1 `values` also comes with R7RS.